# Git not ignoring directories with alphanumeric patterns

Tags: git

I am trying to ignore some directories that are output as job logs.

```
ls -l
drwxr-xr-x  4 user  CHARLES\Domain Users  128 Sep 12 21:36 337c6c86-d49b-43cf-89ac-35c110ec6412

cat .gitignore
^[0-9a-z]+-[0-9a-z]+-[0-9a-z]+-[0-9a-z]+-[0-9a-z]+/$
^[0-9a-z]+-[0-9a-z]+-[0-9a-z]+-[0-9a-z]+-[0-9a-z]+$
```

But git has been refusing to ignore it.

Does git ignore have some special rules about regex patterns?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

Thanks Tim for suggesting clarifying:

What's shown above is a minimum reproducible example, where the git repo has a single sub directory with name `337c6c86-d49b-43cf-89ac-35c110ec6412`.
Then the content of the `.gitignore` file is show with a `cat`.

Comment: You should edit your question and provide the exact path(s) where these UUID folder names would be appearing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.gitignore` obeys only *glob* expressions; it has no regular expression syntax.

In glob format, your options are:

- `[`: characters from a set: match exactly one such character
- `?`: match any character (but always exactly one, a la `.` in a regex)
- `*`: match zero or more characters

These are applied on a per-component basis.  Anchoring (`^` and `$`) is always implied: `a?c` matches the names `aac` and `abc` but never `abcd` or `dabc`.

(Git's rules get a little more complicated if you include slashes, e.g., `**` can match any number of sub-components; but let's just avoid that for now.)

As long as your names are fixed length, and the characters are hexadecimal (in the set `[0-9a-f]`), you can use:

```
[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]-[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]-[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]-[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]-[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]
```

(which I obtained by feeding in your example and using

```
s/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f]/g
```

as an editor command, e.g., in sed or vi).